# Amazon Rekognition print result gives IndexError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to print out results from an Amazon Rekognition call, but it returns the error:

> list index out of range: IndexError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 57, in lambda_handler
>
> time = response['Persons'][0]['Timestamp']
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I put the index[0], I don't really see why it will happen to out of index range.

Can any one help please?

```
response = get_face_search(jobID)
time = response['Persons'][0]['Timestamp']
print(time)

#below is the format:
--------------------------------------------
{
'JobStatus': 'IN_PROGRESS'|'SUCCEEDED'|'FAILED',
'StatusMessage': 'string',
'NextToken': 'string',
'VideoMetadata': {
    'Codec': 'string',
    'DurationMillis': 123,
    'Format': 'string',
    'FrameRate': ...,
    'FrameHeight': 123,
    'FrameWidth': 123
},
'Persons': [
    {
        'Timestamp': 123,
        'Person': {
            'Index': 123,
            'BoundingBox': {
                'Width': ...,
                'Height': ...,
                'Left': ...,
                'Top': ...
            },
            'Face': {
                'BoundingBox': {
                    'Width': ...,
                    'Height': ...,
                    'Left': ...,
                    'Top': ...
                },
                'AgeRange': {
                    'Low': 123,
                    'High': 123
                },
                'Smile': {
                    'Value': True|False,
                    'Confidence': ...
                    },
                ],

                'Pose': {
                    'Roll': ...,
                    'Yaw': ...,
                    'Pitch': ...
                },
                'Quality': {
                    'Brightness': ...,
                    'Sharpness': ...
                },
                'Confidence': ...
            }
        },
        'FaceMatches': [
            {
                'Similarity': ...,
                'Face': {
                    'FaceId': 'string',
                    'BoundingBox': {
                        'Width': ...,
                        'Height': ...,
                        'Left': ...,
                        'Top': ...
                    },
                    'ImageId': 'string',
                    'ExternalImageId': 'string',
                    'Confidence': ...
                }
            },
        ]
    },
]
}
```

Comment: You have shown us the (expected?) format of the response, but what about dumping the structures of the *actual* response?  What if there are no `Persons` elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is that your `response` object does not contain the expected data.

`boto3` requires that all input parameters must be keywords, so:

```
response = get_face_search(jobID)
```

should be:

```
response = get_face_search(JobId = jobID)
```

For an example of a Python script that processes the results of `get_face_search()`, see: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply. I think I found the problem. which is the get face search actually take few seconds to push the result, during the progress, it will show status, like "succeed","in progress","failed", every time  handler tries to print out the result, the get_face_search method get the return value with Persons[], and 'jobstatus' = 'in_progress', I am thinking to write a loop to keep reading jobstatus until it is == succeed.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Officially, Rekognition will send a message to an SNS Topic that can be used to trigger the results retrieval. Otherwise, polling for a response every few seconds will be sufficient.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your suggestion, I am trying to use SNS Topic, just wondering how does the get_face_search() function in another lambda going to retrieve the jobID generated from start_face_search()? Many thanks

Comment: From [Calling Rekognition Video Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/api-video.html#api-video-get-status): _Rekognition Video sends an analysis completion notification to the registered Amazon SNS topic. The notification includes the job identifier and the completion status of the operation in a JSON string._